# C++/CLI debug support under VS2015

Tags: c++, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

Using Visual Studio, I have created Excel addin (.xll), where part of the code (the main project) is written in Native C++, but additional static library is written in C++/CLI (I need to use .NET dlls directly). Whole addin is compiled and started in Excel correctly - I can also debug it using Visual Studio 2013, BUT I cannot debug it using Visual Studio 2015. I can breakpoint in the Native C++ code, but when I try to *Step Into* C++/CLI function, I can see debugger behaves as doing *Step Over*. I am aware of this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/

but it seems like "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" doesn't work in 2015 (while it works in 2013). Is anyone aware how to make VS2015 work for me?

Comment: By design, you cannot single-step from one debugging engine into another.  You have to set a breakpoint to induce the mode switch.

Comment: I don't understand you POV - I can do it without any problem in vs2013, so why do you suggest, I cannot do it in vs2015?

Comment: Stepping between runtimes IS supported.  Make sure you are mixed mode debugging and have symbols loaded for the module you are trying to step into.  Another thing you can try is to turn off Just My Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem but it went away. I must have fiddled with a setting but never figured out specifically what it was.

In Tools>Options>Debugging I've got:
  "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" : off
  "Use Native Compatibility Mode" : on

Also in Project>Properties>Debugging I have:
  Debugger Type: Mixed

Comment: Debugger Type: Mixed in project properties did it for me. I had most options fine and could easily debug from a .NET application into C++/CLI into native code, but this one is required for a native application calling into C++/CLI.